# subprocess doesn't run as sudo even if i do "sudo python test.py"

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run sudo command in a python script and i think using a plaintext password in a python file is not good. So i tried to run the python script using sudo `sudo python test.py`, however the subprocess in the script doesn't seem to be executed using sudo. 

This is how my script looks like:

```
cmd = ./something.exe
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(),  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What should i do to make the subprocess run as sudo?

Comment: Your line `cmd = ./something.exe` is missing quotes, but with the quotes, try this instead: `cmd = 'sudo ./something.exe'`, still sudoing the python command itself.

Comment: `script doesn't seem to be executed using sudo` ... How did you determine that? Also, you mention `.exe` Windows binary, whereas `sudo` is typically a Linux thing.

Comment: Thanks  Grismar, it works now after adding sudo in front of the command!